# Point projection on a polygon along each axis

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, computational-geometry

There is a method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260352/python-concave-hull-polygon-of-a-set-of-lines) that allows defining a concave outline around a 2D set of points.

```
import alphashape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch

points = [(17, 158),(15, 135),(38, 183),(43, 19),(93, 88),(96, 140),(149, 163),(128, 248),(216, 265),(248, 210),(223, 167),(256, 151),(331, 214),(340, 187),(316, 53),(298, 35),(182, 0),(121, 42)]

alpha = 0.95 * alphashape.optimizealpha(points)
hull = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha)
hull_pts = hull.exterior.coords.xy
path = PolygonPatch(hull, fill=False, color='green')
print(path.contains_point([128,248]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(hull_pts[0], hull_pts[1], color='red')
ax.add_patch(path)
```

Now assuming a new point "A", I want to get its projection along each axis on this polygon. That is point "b", and "c" as shown in the below image. Does anyone know a way to get such list of coordinates for each projection?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Constructing a line segment along an axis is a pretty basic process, as is intersecting that line with a figure.

Comment: @Vince but how do we define such line segment in alphashape and see the intersect

Comment: I'd just assemble a pair of two element arrays, much like your `points`, but using the MBR min/max X with the Y of A and the MBR min/max Y with the X of A, then look in the documentation for an intersect function. But you haven't attempted anything yet (or haven't documented it, at least), so we can't really help you.

Comment: @Vince I saw a function for intersect, but am not sure how to define a line with shapely and then use the intersect function

Comment: @Vince I tried intersection in the following link but it does not give me the coordinates of points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925976/get-coordinate-of-points-where-a-line-crosses-a-polygon